# WiFi Connection's Name

Tags: java-me, wifi, nokia

I am Developing a `Java ME` Application. Here I am using `WiFi` `Connection`. Now My Question is how to get a particular `WiFi` Connections name using Java ME Code ?

My Requirement is for Nokia E5 Device only.

Comment: Have you tried [IAP Info API](http://library.developer.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/Java_Developers_Library/GUID-9597E8B4-5551-4D0D-A256-6C045480ED2A.html) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing much research work I found that this is not possible in Java ME Technology to fetch the WiFi Connection's Name.

However Similar Library would be `com.nokia.multisim.networkid` which returns Network ID and Network Short Name.

Answer (score 0):

I Dont Think so it is 100% possible in J2ME and even though if it has worked and there is no guarantee that it will work on all J2ME devices which has Wifi connectivity.

most appropriate answer i have found , please go through it once.

" Much as I hate to put you through all that grief and then not have a simple answer, I don't have a simple answer.

The reason for that is because Java's networking model is based on TCP/IP, and the TCP/IP architecture is based on the idea that applications will neither know nor care about the hardware details of networking. A typical mobile device may contain several different network interfaces (WiFi, Bluetooth, Infrared, USB cable, and so forth), but when an app wants to contact another network node, the app doesn't know which of these interfaces is actually being used. And in fact, if the OS wants to do so, it can use more than one (in parallel) and/or switch interfaces in and out, based on routing criteria such as best measured data rates. Rather like how cell phones route phone calls.

So basic Java/JME won't know anything about WiFi.

However, there is an extension, specified as JSR 309 (http://jsp.org) that looks like it may help. It supports learning about and controlling the network interfaces themselves. The problem is that not all devices will implement this extension, so it will depend on what device(s) you are supporting. "

Comment: Please check my updation in question.

Comment: its a suggestion given to get control over network interfaces and if you are targeting for Nokia e65 device only then have you tried with this IAP Info API from Nokia ?

Comment: Can you share that piece of code and what error/exception are you getting ?

Comment: Sorry , I can't My Company doesn't allow me for it.

Comment: mean to say , after using IAP APi what problem are you facing ?

Comment: I can fetch the type of network as EDGE or wlan, but i dont know how to get the wlan's name.